# How to create and print a highscore file in python

Tags: python, file

I am making a Jeopardy-like game and I am trying to add a high score file at the end. Ideally, I would like it to be where the program would ask you for your name and then it would put your name and the amount of points you have(Accumulated and added together throughout the game) onto a new file and ordered from the highest amount of points to lowest. It would then print this file onto python for you to see all of the high scores. It would print something like this...

John Smith, 100
Joe Ericson, 80
Jim Bob, 40

Here is what I have so far...

```
print "That's the game folks! You finished with a final score of...", points, 'points! Good game, you made the high score list! What is your name?'
name = raw_input()
h = open('highscores.txt', 'w')
h.write(name)
h.write(points)
f.close()
print (highscores.txt)
```

Comment: Does the text file have to be ordered and does it have to be truncated to the e.g. top 10, or can we simply append each new score to the file and only display the top 10? Else we would have to rewrite it on each change.

Comment: FWIW, your file handle magically changed from `h` to `f`. :)

Comment: BTW, you can't write a number directly to a file, you need to convert it to a string.

Comment: Have you done a search on `stackoverflow high score file python`? Surely one of those answers will be applicable...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Python's [ConfigParser module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) - it allows you to manage a simple files with configuration without care about their format.

File's format is like

```
    [section1]
    variable=value

    [section2]
    variable2=value2

    ...
```

so you could have a sections with *Names* and options with *Highscores* like:

```
    #config.cfg file
    [John Smith]
    highscore = 100

    [Joe Ericson]
    highscore = 80
```

then you can read, write and iterate over players with such a simple code

```
    import ConfigParser, os

    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open('config.cfg'))

    for section in config.sections():
        print section, ", ", config.get(section, "highscore")
```

Of course you can write new values into the config files using

```
    RawConfigParser.add_section(section)
    RawConfigParser.set(section, option, value)
```

methods. Your data will be persistent also after end of application life.

Answer (score -2):

You could store the high scores directly in your python file as global variables. After a new game is finished you could check the current high score and bump one out if the current score is higher. 
What you are doing now seems like a difficult solution as you cannot compute anything directly in a text file so you would have to create a separate python program to read the test file, scramble out the scores and find the highest ones

Comment: While it's certainly _possible_ for a Python script to modify its own source this is generally **not** a good design.